# How can i relate different meshes through c# script in unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh

I am a unity newb creating a board game. The board will consist of isles divided in territories, much like continents are in Risk. I have divised the following setup but i have no clue if its the best approach, please point me in the right direction if its not.

I followed this tutorial : http://games.ucla.edu/resource/unity-3-importing-assets-board-making/   and created 3 isle meshes :

[image]

Now i want to obtain the adjacent tiles to each tile. For example in the image, the tiles next to tile1 (including the corner tile). I will need this info to tell a player which territories he is capable of invading. Creating a List  for each tile containing the adjacent tiles crossed my mind, but i find it a poor and sub-optimal solution.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: If the tiles are strictly a rectangular grid on each island, then you can make a 2D array to store references to the tiles, and also store the grid coordinates in each tile for fast neighbor lookup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i did what Agumander suggested in his comment:

> If the tiles are strictly a rectangular grid on each island, then you
>   can make a 2D array to store references to the tiles, and also store
>   the grid coordinates in each tile for fast neighbor lookup.

I used an array structure to for each Island in which each Tile would have its neighbor tile's assigned.

Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 0):

What I did for a similar problem was on the same track as you suggested in your question. However, instead of just mindlessly assigning lists in the inspector, I wrote an editor script that will automatically find and assign the lists based on how far apart tiles are. Then if there were any discrepancies I would just change those by hand.